# Hack a unity game to load a secret level in the build

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, ctf

I am doing a ctf where I am supposed to hack a unity game and load a level which is in the build, but isn't supposed to be opened by default. I was thinking about using cheat engine since for some reason dnSpy doesn't do anything when I edit the assembly C# DLL.

Comment: Use Cheat Engine and modify game variables such that you'll pass a level
There's also a slight chance you could use ```SceneManager```

Comment: CSCG ctf right?